# Unity is always throwing a Win32 Exception

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity always throws the same Win32 Exception.

I've downloaded other versions of Unity, but nothing seems to fix this issue.
This popped up first when I could not attach a script to a game object and the console showed that either the name of the class or file name was wrong.
After that, this has been a regular issue.

> Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Users\Aniketh Suresh\Desktop\Aniketh's Stuff\Projects\Unity\2019.1.8f1\Editor\Data\Tools\RoslynScripts\unity_csc.bat', CommandLine='/noconfig @Temp/UnityTempFile-699879dd9a6c79e4298a8ff4d40c9db1', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity “The associated script can not be loaded” and “Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450050/unity-the-associated-script-can-not-be-loaded). This is due to a bug in unity involving directory names that have apostrophes in them.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been looking all over for a solution so thank you!

Comment: Are there any other characters that could cause this? I was hopeful on finding this, as the project did have a bunch of files with apostrophes in the path (from a plugin - "NatureManufacture Assets") but removing them prior to importing the project doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.